# Regex to remove HTML comments from asp.net Webform but preserve #include and knockout statements

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, knockout.js, webforms

I want to minify asp.net webform pages in ASP.Net.
So before deployment, I use this awesome [HTMLMinifier.exe](https://github.com/deanhume/html-minifier)
According to this utility, it removes both HTML and knockout comments irrespective of ignoringKnockout comment.It also removes the #include file from the aspx.

```
1. <!-- normal html comments -->
2. <!-- ko if:knockoutComments() -->
3. <!-- /ko -->
4. <!-- #include file="" -->
```

I need to replace only 1st statement.
All feasible regex and non-regex solutions are welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a suitable regex for that:

```
<!-- (?!(ko|\/ko|#include)).*? -->
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! You saved my day :)

Comment: @sushilkanojia no problem, this is whats SO is for ;) please remember upvoting and marking the right answer! have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

It's probably best to go with the regex that knockout's source code uses internally:

> ```
> var startCommentRegex = commentNodesHaveTextProperty 
>     ? /^<!--\s*ko(?:\s+([\s\S]+))?\s*-->$/ 
>     : /^\s*ko(?:\s+([\s\S]+))?\s*$/;
> var endCommentRegex =   commentNodesHaveTextProperty 
>     ? /^<!--\s*\/ko\s*-->$/ 
>     : /^\s*\/ko\s*$/;
> ```

You'll have to rewrite them to whatever other-than-js-regex-syntax you're using though...

Source: https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/virtualElements.js#L15